# ATL errors compiling 64-bit COM excel addin

Tags: visual-c++, com, excel-2010, atl

I have a C++ ATL COM adding that implements some utility functions that refer to the Excel API:

```
void DoSomething(CComPtr<Excel::Range> &masterCell)
{
    // ...
    CComPtr<Excel::Range> cell = masterCell->Offset[vertical][horizontal];
    // ...
}
```

When compiling an excel addin for x64 I'm getting lots of spurious errors such as:

```
cannot convert from 'Excel::Range' to 'ATL::CComPtr<T>'
```

However, when I compile for Win32 there is no problem. The helper utility functions are not exposed as excel UDF's so I don't think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768016/vs-com-project-compiles-in-32bit-but-throws-error-c2259-when-trying-to-compile-6) is applicable since the function does not have a `STDMETHODIMP` part.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel::Range comes from the following statements: #import "Excel.tlb" named_guids auto_rename ... and ... using namespace Excel; This version of Excel.tlb was generated from a 32-bit version of Excel. Do I need to generate a 64-bit one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! Turns out that I was trying to reference a 32-bit excel installation in a 64-bit build:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f069ea06-b888-47c0-9ec8-c6cf8a59d9b1/atl-errors-compiling-64bit-com-excel-addin?forum=exceldev

Installing 64-bit excel fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`CComPtr` accepts an interface as a template argument, while `Range` is dispinterface. You need `CComPtr<Excel::IRange>` instead.